# How to parse the information to a regular string

Tags: javascript, node.js

im having some trouble while processing some information, the thing is i have an npm module that is called pdf-parser it basically reads a pdf and extracts the information inside. What is need next is to send the information to an API that punctuates how well written is the text.

Thing is when i log the information on display it looks like this:

```
Entornos personales de aprendizaje
 PLE (personal learning environmnent o entorno personal del aprendizaje) es un concepto de
 mucho interés y causa de debate en los círculos de la tecnología educativa.
 Un PLE puede definirse como el conjunto de herramientas tecnológicas elegidas como
 integradas y utilizadas por un individuo para acceder a las nuevas fuentes de conocimiento.
 Un PLE se conforma por tres procesos básicos según Atwell estos son: leer, reflexionar y
 compartir.
 1.La fuentes a las que accedo me ofrecen información.
 2.Entornos o servicios en los que puedo transformar la información.
 3.Entornos donde me relaciono con las personas de las que aprendo.
 Donde acceder a la información: Sitios web, videos, archivos multimedia, noticas, etc.
 Donde modificar la información: Herramientas de dedición, mapas conceptuales,
 cronogramas, creación de presentaciones, etc.
 Donde puedo relacionarme con otros: Redes sociales.
```

But the information inside the object that i made looks like this:

```
    '\n' +
'\n' +
'Entornos personales de aprendizaje\n' +
'PLE (personal learning environmnent o entorno personal del aprendizaje) es un concepto de \n' +
'mucho interés y causa de debate en los círculos de la tecnología educativa.\n' +
'Un PLE puede definirse como el conjunto de herramientas tecnológicas elegidas como \n' +
'integradas y utilizadas por un individuo para acceder a las nuevas fuentes de conocimiento.\n' +
'Un PLE se conforma por tres procesos básicos según Atwell estos son: leer, reflexionar y \n' +
'compartir.\n' +
'1.La fuentes a las que accedo me ofrecen información.\n' +
'2.Entornos o servicios en los que puedo transformar la información.\n' +
'3.Entornos donde me relaciono con las personas de las que aprendo.\n' +
'Donde acceder a la información: Sitios web, videos, archivos multimedia, noticas, etc.\n' +
'Donde modificar la información: Herramientas de dedición, mapas conceptuales, \n' +
'cronogramas, creación de presentaciones, etc.\n' +
'Donde puedo relacionarme con otros: Redes sociales.'
```

Is there a js function that parses the information into a simple string, because the API won't give the same results while the text is written "codelike"

Thanks in advance and sorry form y rough english

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question. You have a javascript string literal in the second panel that gets displayed like showed in the first panel. You say the text is written "codelike". What do you mean? What's wrong with the string? Actually it's confusing also the fact you are using single quotes (they don't expand the \n placeholders like double quotes are intended to do)

Comment: Can you please describe the **problem** that you are facing and the **expected result**? Your question is a bit unclear

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.